# how to release the apk for ionic2 app?

Tags: android-studio, ionic2, signed-apk

I am new to ionic2 platform. I created one ionic2 app in android studio. Now I want to generate apk for publish the app in play store. I have knowledge on android apps in android studio.

But when I created ionic2 app in android studio it was not showing build variants to change the modes and in Build option 
[image: Image here] also there was no option like "Generated signed APK".

please any one help me how can I generated the apk for publish in play store